# Git Release Need to go back a release

Tags: git, release

I have read a few similar questions however I didn't get what I wanted.

I just pushed a release to production(live) and for some reason there is something not working. I want to go back one release so I can fix and then repush the release. Is that something that is easy to do? I need to keep the code and be able to re-push. Please any help would be a life saver!!!

Comment: Is the question here how to push an older version to production? Is the question here how to check out an older version? What do you need help with specifically? What does "push[ing] a release to production" look like in your environment?

Comment: On Production I have release v5.7 I need to backwards to release v5.6 so that the code I just pushed isn't breaking the site. When I do that Can I checkout the release on my local and fix it or do I have to create a new feature branch?

Comment: What does pushing to production involve for you? How does it work? What do you need to do to do it? You can checkout any revision you want. You can only work from the head of a branch though. How you have to branch/tag/etc. the fix work you are going to do depends *entirely* on local policy and isn't something we can tell you.

Comment: As of right now I build git flow features and then finish them. After that I build the release and finish that. Then I push to bitbucket and then log into prod and fetch all then rebase origin/master. 
So if I knew which HEAD@{4}: to go to I could reset backward? Don't really have a local policy.

Comment: You should know where you were last production update then easily enough. It should be the last master (assuming you only merge to master for/at release time). If not and you don't pull onto production often then it should just be the most recent HEAD on the production machine I would imagine. (You should probably also have a tag for it. If you don't you should start doing that.)

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that you should get a Git expert administrator to take care of this for you. It'll be much safer. In lieu of that, you can try following these instructions.

```
git checkout <release>
```

The switches your active branch to the branch you want to rescue (of course you will need to substitute  for the branch's actual name)

```
git branch placeholder
```

This will keep a branch called "placeholder" on your current state so that you do not lose anything.

```
git log --decorate --oneline
```

Find the oid, tag, or branch (aka the committish) of where you want to reset yourself to:

```
git reset <committish> --hard
```

This will move your active branch back to the point of the committish.

Now you're in a neat state, you've basically undone your previous mess up. You can push this to the server if all you want to do is revert state (note: you'll need force push permissions to do so).

```
git push --force
```

At any rate, I recommend that you also push the placeholder branch in case your local system fails or whatever horrible things Murphy has in store for you.

```
git checkout placeholder
git push -u origin placeholder
```

Per any information given on SO, there's no warranties and this is only meant as guidance, not professional help.